# Calling a string getter function from a header file

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning C++, and I'm just messing around with putting classes in separate files for practice. I have a getter function, which returns a `string` (because the variable is saved as a `string`). However, from my `main()` function, I am not sure how to call it. I know the problem is probably that I need to include `string` somewhere when I call the object, but I have no idea how to format it.

I know this is a pretty newbie questions, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere. Could someone help me out?

(p.s. I'm not trying to get this specific code to work, since it's useless. I'm just trying to learn how to apply it for future reference).

I've tried throwing in `string` in a couple of places when calling or creating the object, but I always get an error. I know I could get around it by not encapsulating the variable or not having a separate class file, but that's not what I want.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "usernameclass.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    usernameclass usernameobject;
    usernameobject.getUsername();
    return 0;
}
```

usernameclass.h

```
#ifndef USERNAMECLASS_H
#define USERNAMECLASS_H
#include <string>

class usernameclass
{
    public:
        usernameclass();
        std::string getUsername();
        void setUsername(std::string name);
        askUsername();

    private:
        std::string usernameVar = "test";
};

#endif
```

usernameclass.cpp

```
#include "usernameclass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "username.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string usernameclass::getUsername(){
    return usernameVar;
    cout << "test cout" << endl;
}

usernameclass::askUsername(){
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    setUsername(name);
    cout << "Ah, so your name is "+usernameVar+", great name I guess!" << endl;
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    cout << "You're about to do some stuff, so get ready!" << endl;
}

usernameclass::usernameclass(){}

void usernameclass::setUsername(string name){
    string* nameptr = &usernameVar;
    *nameptr = name;
}
```

Expected result: runs `getUsername()` function and returns `usernameVar`

Actual result: doesn't run the `getUsername()` function

Comment: Re: "always get an error" -- read the error message. Carefully. If you don't understand it, post it. Here's a hint: `askUsername()` doesn't have a return type; it should.

Comment: Are these the only two files? If so - you need a "usernameclass.cpp" file which includes "usernameclass.h" and implements the getUsername() function. Then over in main() you'd typically want to do something with the result; for example, `std::cout << usernameobject.getUsername();`.

Comment: you return just before the cout ;)
The ```cout << "test cout" << endl;``` is never executed (aka. dead code)

Comment: @johan d. Thanks! That was the problem! (facepalm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current code would not compile, because you have not specified return type of '*askUsername*()' routine, which is '*void*', I believe.

Other things are good, apart from an output in '*getUsername*()', which happens **after** returning from the function and about which you should have received a warning, I guess.

To the question: you can call that 'get' method in '*main*()' as:

```
cout << usernameobject.getUsername();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm really dumb, it seems to be working now. I was looking for the cout statement as an identifier that it was running properly because i'm a pleb, and I had it after the return so it wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be structured more like this instead:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "usernameclass.h"

int main()
{
    usernameclass usernameobject;

    // optional:
    // usernameobject.askUsername();

    // do something with usernameobject.getUsername() as needed...

    return 0;
}
```

usernameclass.h

```
#ifndef USERNAMECLASS_H
#define USERNAMECLASS_H

#include <string>

class usernameclass
{
public:
    std::string getUsername() const;
    void setUsername(std::string name);
    void askUsername();

private:
    std::string usernameVar = "test";
};

#endif
```

usernameclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "usernameclass.h"

std::string usernameclass::getUsername() const {
    return usernameVar;
}

void usernameclass::setUsername(std::string name) {
    usernameVar = name;
}

void usernameclass::askUsername() {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "What is your name?" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, std::name);
    setUsername(name);
    std::cout << "Ah, so your name is " << getUsername() << ", great name I guess!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "You're about to do some stuff, so get ready!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much! I learned a lot from the way you structured this instead of the way I had it. It makes a lot of sense this way. Much cleaner and more professional.